# Update nested models in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I'm wanting to build a Rails API that creates nested records in the database.

I'm wanting to post data to the database for **nested** or say associated model with a **has_ many** association [see code below].

**Is this the correct approach?** Or is there any alternate approach for the `update` action? I want to record the users `Address` which will be in array of hashes in json format.

I have two models `User` and `Address`.
Association is `User` has_many `Addresses`.

My update action:

```
   def update
    @user = User.find(id: params[:id])

    if @user.update(first_name: params[:first_name],email: params[:email],phone: params[:phone],password: Time.now.to_i, gstin: params[:gstin],addresses)
      @user.addresses.each do |a|

        a.update_attributes(first_name: params['first_name'],last_name: params['last_name'],city: params['city'],state: params['state'],phone: params['phone'],zip: params['zip'],address: params['address'])
      end  
      render json: @user, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end
```

Comment: Take a look at [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Can you expose your JSON? It's not necessary to store user's attributes in Address objects

Comment: Actually first_name,last_name are also attributes of addreses .my json data for user comes in params while creating user .first_name:syedemail:syed@instadel.co phone:8880076600gstin:123.                                                              
 but Address comes in json format.addresses:[{"first_name": "syed", "last_name": "shahid",  "state": "Karnataka", "city": "Banglore", "address": "xyz and asdf asdf asdf", "zip": "563101", "phone": "8880076601" }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and writing the answer for the people who get stuck.

As I was not using strong params and I needed only the address in json format, I parsed the address `json` like this:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(first_name: params[:first_name],email: params[:email],phone: params[:phone], gstin: params[:gstin])
      updated_addreses = JSON.parse(params[:addresses])
        updated_addreses.each do |add|
          @user.addresses.update(first_name: add['first_name'],city: add['city'],state: add['state'],phone: add['phone'],zip: add['zip'],address: add['address'])
        end  
      render json: {user_id: @user.id.to_s}, status: 200
    else
      render json: { errors: @user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

thats not correct way to do
you should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
Class User 
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

for more details and example [follow this](https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/)

Comment: Bro , i have already added accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,while building the create action for users. i want to update action?

Comment: bro, you can use the same way to update as u did in create just do `user.update(user_params)` and you need to modified your `params` according to your model attribute in `strong parameter`